# Update foreign key in Spring Boot with a POST request

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, postman

I am trying to make a put request using Postman with Spring Boot. The idea is to give the subscription object a foreign key value with a put request or post.

I get this error[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifAqQ.png)

Postman input : [INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO9Ku.png)

The user class : [User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA3t1.png)

The subscription class : [Subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oYO9.png)

Update method : [Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Byg.png)

I've already searched the internet and  I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of textual data. Include the code and exception stacktraces as code-formatted text in your question. Also, using all capitals is the internet equivalent of shouting, which is pretty rude to do to people you want to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller path in the image is `subscription/{id}` and you're trying to request `user/{id}`. As far as I understand, you're requesting the wrong URL.

By the way, when you're performing multiple interactions with the Database, use `@Transactional` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

When i read your code, what you trying to is getting the data from client Entity then save toSubscription Entity if Exist using PUT as update . How about make validation of Client for Post mapping if meet the requirement then save it also to Subscription.